# ¿Cómo se puede ocultar/mostrar botones desde otro botón?

Tags: java, android

tengo en una clase Fragment puesto unos botones, donde intento que, al pulsar sobre un botón, unos botones se oculten y otros se muestren.

Tengo los botones llamados Línea 1 y Línea 2, que al pulsarlos tendría que mostrar debajo los botones que hay ocultos, y en el caso de tener los botones a la vista se tendrían que ocular.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no consigo que el código funcione, ¿me podéis ayudar?

Esta es la clase **Fragment** (**Estaci2.java**)

```
public class Estaci2 extends Fragment {

ImageButton boton_linea1;
ImageButton boton_linea2;
ImageButton boton_s_ga;
ImageButton boton_s_vi;

public Estaci2() {
}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.estacio2, container, false );

        boton_linea1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_Linea_1);
        boton_linea2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_Linea_2);
        boton_s_ga = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_s_ga);
        boton_s_vi = rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_s_vi);

        boton_linea1.setOnClickListener(this);
        boton_linea2.setOnClickListener(this);
        boton_s_ga.setOnClickListener(this);
        boton_s_ga.setOnClickListener(this);

        boton_s_ga.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Esta_S_Ga fragment = new Esta_S_Ga();
                FragmentTransaction ftEs = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //FragmentTransaction ftEs = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //ftEs.replace(R.id.frame_container, new Esta_S_Ga());
                ftEs.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                ftEs.addToBackStack(null);
                ftEs.commit();

            }
        });

        boton_s_vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Esta_S_Vi fragment = new Esta_S_Vi();
                FragmentTransaction ftEs = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //FragmentTransaction ftEs = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                //ftEs.replace(R.id.frame_container, new Esta_S_Vi());
                ftEs.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
                ftEs.addToBackStack(null);
                ftEs.commit();

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bt_Linea_1:
            if(boton_linea1.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                boton_s_ga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                boton_s_vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                boton_s_ga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bt_Linea_2:
            if(boton_s_vi.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                boton_s_vi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                boton_s_ga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                boton_s_vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Y este su MXL (**estaci2.xml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu.Estaci2">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_Linea_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descri_linea1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/linea_1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_s_ga"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descri_s_ga"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_Linea_1"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/s_ga"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_Linea_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descri_linea2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_s_ga"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/linea_2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_s_vi"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descri_s_vi"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_Linea_2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/s_vi"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error que se muestra al pulsar los botones **S Ga** y **S Vi** para llamar a otro `Fragment`

```
2018-12-04 11:08:44.915 19253-19253/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu     E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f070046 (com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu:id/frame_container) for fragment     Esta_S_Vi{b91057b #0 id=0x7f070046}
2018-12-04 11:08:44.915 19253-19253/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu     E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
2018-12-04 11:08:44.964 19253-19253/com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu, PID: 19253
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f070046 (com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu:id/frame_container) for fragment Esta_S_Vi{b91057b #0 id=0x7f070046}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1413)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola @Socu hace tiempo no te veìa por aquí, te comento que el método onClick() que contiene la lógica no se llama ya que necesitas implementar la interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón por la cual no se esta llamando el método `onClick()` es porque tu clase Fragment debe ademas implementar la interface `View.OnClickListener`:

```
public class Estaci2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
```

de esta forma el método se llamara sin problema:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bt_Linea_1:
            if(boton_linea1.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                boton_s_ga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                boton_s_vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                boton_s_ga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bt_Linea_2:
            if(boton_s_vi.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
            {
                boton_s_vi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                boton_s_ga.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else
            {
                boton_s_vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Para que funcionen también los botones boton_s_ga y boton_s_vi debes agregar su id e implementas su lógica:

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bt_Linea_1:
                ...
                ...
                break;
            case R.id.bt_Linea_2:
                ...
                ...
                break;
            case R.id.boton_s_ga:
                ...
                ...
                break;
            case R.id.boton_s_vi:
                ...
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Jorgesys cuando CajamiSoft comento que hay que poner ** implements View.OnClickListener** lo cambie y seguía sin funcionar, fallo mío por probar solo un botón, porque el código tenía un error, en `case R.id.bt_Linea_1: if(boton_linea1.getVisibility……` tenía que ser `if(boton_s_ga.getVisibility…….`, ahora si nuestra los botones ocultos, lo que no funcionan son los botones **S Ga** y **SVi**, cuando se pulsan no hacen nada, no sé porque pero esto es otra pelea que tengo, nunca me ha funcionado pasar de un Fragment a otro Fragment :( :( y creo que aquí tengo otra retención :(

Comment: Hola de nuevo, he puesto en el primer post el código que muestra al pulsar los botones que se encuentran escondidos, por si a vosotros os da una pista de porque no deja mostrar el otro Fragmen

Comment: @SoCu implements View.OnClickListener va a provocar que se llame onClick()  lo cual era el problema. Ahora comentas que cuando pulsas id.boton_s_ga y boton_s_vi no realizan acción se debe a que debes agregarlos en el switch e implementar su lógica.

Comment: @SoCu ahora el error que presentas se debe a otra causa diferente, dentro del xml   R.layout.estaciones2  no se encuentra el elemento frame_container.